# Building LLVM with cmake. Does -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 get overridden?

Tags: cmake, build, llvm

I try to build LLVM.
This is the way I try …

```
    mkdir -p src/llvm-$(LLVM_VERSION).src/build
    cd src/llvm-$(LLVM_VERSION).src/build && \
        $(CMAKE) -GNinja \
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(BUNDLE) \
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++11 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -l:libstdc++.a" \
            -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86;NVPTX" \
            -DLLVM_PARALLEL_COMPILE_JOBS=$(BUILD_JOBS) \
            -DLLVM_PARALLEL_LINK_JOBS=2 \
            -DLLVM_USE_CRT_RELEASE=MD \
            -DLLVM_USE_CRT_DEBUG=MDd \
            -DLLVM_STATIC=ON \
            -DLLVM_INCLUDE_TESTS=OFF \
            -DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF \
            -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_C_DYLIB=OFF \
            -DLLVM_ENABLE_TERMINFO=OFF \
            -DLLVM_ENABLE_UNWIND_TABLES=OFF \
            -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON \
            .. && \
        $(CMAKE) --build . && \
        $(CMAKE) --build . --target install
```

You can see -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 in -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. After LLVM finished compiling, libLLVM*.a still contain abi:cxx11 symbols.

llvm-config reveals, llvm build process completely ignored "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" flag.

```
> ./bundle/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags
-I/home/leonard/Documents/Develop/build_as_deps/bundle/include -std=c++11   -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_DEBUG -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

Do you have an idea how to build llvm in a way that disables abi:cxx11 symbols and prevents "-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" to be overridden?

Comment: I wrote it in my question description. But it seems I need to ensure it is noticed.
Please note, -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 is defined inside -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.   
Still, I get abi:cxx11 symbols.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confusing the cmake options (which are specified with via `-D`) with C/C++ compiler macro (which are also specified via `-D`, but to compiler). cmake happily ignored your `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI`, because it's not a cmake option (and you should see a warning about this, that the value is unused by the build system).

Since you need to add extra macro definition, you'd need to change `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` cmake variable.

Comment: Not sure, because -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI is already used inside CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS string. Its a long line, need horizontal scroll to become visible.

Comment: I changed order of arguments in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. To improve its visibility. Now there is no need to scroll.